# How to Install ffmpeg command into my docker

Tags: docker, go, ffmpeg, docker-compose

Im am doing that in my docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
    image: golang:1.14.3
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" ## Share API port with host machine.
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - ffmpeg
    volumes:
        - .:/go/src/go-intelligent-monitoring-system
        - /home/:/home/
    working_dir: /go/src/go-intelligent-monitoring-system
    command: apt-get install ffmpeg ########-------<<<<<<---------#################
    command: go run main.go
```

But when I use it on my code, I have this error:
--> **""exec: "ffmpeg": executable file not found in $PATH""**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last `command` in compose file will take effect, so you didn't have chance to install ffmpeg with your current compose file.

As a replacement, you should install `ffmpeg` in your customized dockerfile like next, refers to [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build):

```
app:
  build: ./dir
```

Put you customized `Dockerfile` in above `dir` like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:1.14.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg -y
```